# How to turn off echo while executing a shell script Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo

Here is a simple thing i was working on

```
 echo "please enter a command"
 read x
 $x
 checkexitstatus()
 {...}
```

`checkexit` status is a ifloop created somewhere else just to check exit status

What i want to know is
Is there any way that when i run the $x that it wont be displayed on the screen
I want to know if it is possible without redirecting the output to a file

Comment: `$x > /dev/null` instead of `$x`.  To silence error messages too, `$x > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: @AkyJ If you want to store the output to a file, you should use something else than `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Bash redirection :

- `command 1> /.../path_to_file` => to redirect stdout into path_to_file.

`command > /.../path_to_file` is a shortcut of the previous command.

- `command 2> /.../path_to_file` => to redirect stderr into path_to_file

To do both at the same time to the same output: `command >/.../path_to_file 2>&1`.

`2>&1` means redirect `2` (stderr) to `1` (stdout which became path_to_file). 
You could replace `path_to_file` by `/dev/null` if you don't want to retrieve the output of your command.

Otherwise, you could also store the output of a command :

```
$ var=$(command) # Recent shell like Bash or KSH
$ var=`command` # POSIX compliant
```

In this example, the output of `command` will be stored in `$var`.

Comment: Thanks for the info and explaining what 2&>1 actually does :)

Answer (score 8):

No, it isn't possible.

```
$x &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
i used $x > /dev/null 2>&1 as suggested by devnull

Comment: @AkyJ If you want to store the output to a file, you should use something else than `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to turn off only the `echo` command and not other commands that send their output to the `stdout`, as the title suggests, you can possibly (it may break the code) create an alias for `echo`

```
alias echo=':'
```

now `echo` is an alias for `noop`. You can `unalias` it by `unalias echo`.